# Having @ExceptionHandler annotations in spring controller hangs Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a very strange issue with Tomcat and Spring application. I have a controller which is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` annotation:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler({ResourceNotFoundException.class})
    public ModelAndView handleException(ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName(e.getViewName());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

When I try to restart Tomcat on the start up when the application is being deployed, I see the log:

```
2014-01-20 15:15:15,197 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO   ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in exceptionController
```

After that nothing happens. Tomcat just hangs and I have to kill java process and run it again, sometimes it starts up without problem, logs just keep going after this and app is deployed but more often I get this hang.

I've tried to google it, checked all the logs. Nothing, no idea what's wrong here. Did anyone already experience something like this before? How can I solve this?

```
Tomcat is: 7.0.35
Spring 4.0.0 (tested also with 3.2.6 - the same issue)
```

Please advice.

Comment: I very much doubt this is the cause. Can you try debugging and stepping through the code that registers your `@ExceptionHandler` methods?

Comment: It looks like you may be creating an infinite loop here. You're not finding a resource, presumably the view, and then you're using that same view again, which in turn will cause it to not be found and that will trigger this handler which will then try to use the not found resource again...

Comment: When Tomcat hangs take a thread dump instead of debug and look for the exact area which is causing a deadlock or something similar.